# Safecracker parse error

Tags: safecracker

I'm receiving a PHP parse error whenever the safecracker tag is parsed. The error is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /srv/sites/xxx/xxx/xxx/expressionengine/modules/safecracker/libraries/safecracker_lib.php on line 2083

Running EE 2.5.3 on PHP 5.4.15.

Comment: It doesn't seem Safecraker module error. Can you share the safecracker tag here.

Comment: Sure! Sorry, should have done that. I stripped out everything but:{exp:safecracker channel="blog"}   
<input name="title" type="text">
 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:safecracker}

Comment: are you submitting the entry with guest member?

Comment: I'm pretty sure EE is not tested/known to work with on PHP 5.4.

Comment: The form won't even parse at all. I'm getting the error because I'm logged in as a superadmin and have debugging set to 1.

Comment: I've been running on 5.4 for sometime now and have had Safecracker working as well. This all started when I tried to fix the checkbox bug. I reverted code but then got this fatal error.

Comment: For a possible resolve to this entry refer to this issue: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13534/safecracker-error-after-upgrading-from-2-5-5-to-2-7