# Safecracker error after upgrading from 2.5.5 to 2.7

Tags: safecracker, 2.7.0

I see this in pages where I have Safecracker forms

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(/home/dsvrtwo/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/safecracker/mod.safecracker.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 1011
```

Any idea why it is still pointing to "safecracker"?

In the Channel Form [documentation page](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html), I don't see any opening/closing tag documentation. Am I supposed to rename my Safecracker forms?

**UPDATE**: I found this [Channel Form examples page](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/examples.html).

So I tried renaming my tag to `{exp:channel:form}`.

However, I get 2 new errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Channel_form_lib::$EE
Filename: safecracker_registration/ext.safecracker_registration.php
Line Number: 125

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: safecracker_registration/ext.safecracker_registration.php
Line Number: 125
```

Comment: I need to work on Safecracker Registration compatibility with 2.7. This is on my list of things to do, and just released Photo Frame 2.7 compatibility. Give me a little more time and I will get this fixed for you.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell Glad to know it was not just me messing up the upgrade steps. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @justinkimbrell This might be an irrelevant question but does uninstalling the old safecracker module going to affect this plugin?

Comment: Has anything been resolved with Safecracker and EE 2.7?

Comment: @Linebacker76 The issue is with Safecracker Registration, not Safecracker/Channel Forms. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: We just upgraded our site and are having this issue also. I thought safecracker was now part of the default install of Exp Eng. Any news on how to fix this?

Comment: I found the issue we were having. When upgrading to Exp Eng 2.7 the "safecracker" tag and module are no longer used. But Safecracker was still leftover in the modules directory. I deleted that folder from the server and the page loaded but with a template tag error about exp:safecracker. Then the exp:safecracker tag on the template had to be replaced with exp:channel:form and the page now worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safecracker error after upgrading from 2.6.1 to 2.7](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13887/safecracker-error-after-upgrading-from-2-6-1-to-2-7)

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine is not pointing to safecracker, an add-on is. I hope you were upgrading on a development/testing environment. It's one of those cases where you have to wait for all your required add-ons to be compatible with the new version of EE before upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade EE, installer automatically changes your all templates, but it only changes the templates in database. If you use templates in files, you have to change manually all your templates and replace {safecracker} tags with new {exp:channel:form} tags. Actually you can open the template in control panel, and copy/paste the automatically updated code to the template in file. It took my one night and few more grey hairs :) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue asked by arvinsim , my form templates would not parse at all after my upgrade from 2.5.5 to 2.7 (and php error was the same). I only needed to replace {exp:safecracker} with {exp:channel:form}.